# Добавление меток Я.карт по дата атрибутам

Tags: javascript, jquery, яндекс-карты

Есть несколько блоков с дата-атрибутами, значение которых являются координаты. 
Нужно перебрать все блоки у которых есть эти дата-атрибуты и добавить метки на карту. Вроде бы, все просто, но что то не получается и выбивает ошибку

```
<div class="main-addresses__item" data-coord="[55.141524, 61.392357]"></div>
<div class="main-addresses__item" data-coord="[55.142140, 61.429013]"></div>

var Placemark = {};

ymaps.ready(function () {
            console.log('2');
            var myMap = new ymaps.Map('addresses__map', {
                center: [55.034842, 61.368563],
                zoom: 10,
                controls: ['zoomControl']
            }, {
                suppressMapOpenBlock: true,
            });
            console.log('3');
            myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');

            $('.main-addresses__item').each(function() {
                var obj = $(this).attr("data-coord");
                console.log(obj);

                myMap.geoObjects
                .add(new ymaps.Placemark([obj]), {
                    iconCaption: 'test'
                }, {
                    preset: 'islands#greenDotIconWithCaption',
                    iconColor: '#ed4543'
                });

            }); //each

        });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно создали объект Placemark, и нет преобразования из строки в массив

```js
var Placemark = {};

ymaps.ready(function() {
  console.log('2');
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('myMap', {
    center: [55.034842, 61.368563],
    zoom: 10,
    controls: ['zoomControl']
  }, {
    suppressMapOpenBlock: true,
  });
  console.log('3');
  myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');

  $('.main-addresses__item').each(function() {
    var obj = $(this).attr("data-coord");
    obj = JSON.parse(obj); //преобразовываем в объект

    //console.log(obj); //тоже самое, но уже не строка, а объект

    myMap.geoObjects
      .add(new ymaps.Placemark(obj, { //тут была неправильная ")" и "[obj]"
        iconCaption: 'test'
      }, {
        preset: 'islands#greenDotIconWithCaption',
        iconColor: '#ed4543'
      }));

  }); //each
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="main-addresses__item" data-coord="[55.141524, 61.392357]"></div>
<div class="main-addresses__item" data-coord="[55.142140, 61.429013]"></div>

<!-- Область показа карты -->
<div id="myMap" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробнейший ответ!

Answer (score 0):

В инструментах разработчика есть пункт Source, справа есть кнопка в виде паузы, нажми ее и перезагрузи страницу, когда произойдет ошибка скрипт остановиться на ней и можно будет посмотреть трасировку, из нее тебе станет понятно в какой момент происходит ошибка и изза чего, также ты будешь видеть данные которые есть в настояший момент.

На будушее если хочешь чтобы тебе написали ответ или поправили код надо выкладывать мин пример.